# How to keep my shares when moving a pool server?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, pushpool

I have a question...

1. If I'm mining with a litecoind/bitcoind process, and a pushpool. How can i move the whole shablam to a new server/copmputer WHILEST saving the progress I have on this current round?
2. Also, can i move the litecoind/bitcoind and/or pushpoold service and files without having to rebuild them from source on the new machine?

Help is highly appriciated!

Comment: Are you hosting a pushpool yourself? Doesn't the pool save the amount of shares you submitted to your account so that your progress is automatically saved to your account?

Comment: The answer on your second question will heavily depend on how similar the two machines are you are moving between.

Comment: Yes, I'm hosting a pushpool myself. I don't know... All I know is that it puts shares into a database, that's neat and all, but does the progress actually save on the litecoind "account" ?

Comment: Oh and the second question, well it's basicly the same machine, one more core and double the ram. Same Ubuntu image.

Comment: @StevenRoose Also, another question... If pushpoold crashes, and i force restart the whole server with shutdown -r now. That progrss is saved as well? I hope?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not the person that can help you.

Comment: @StevenRoose Alright, thanks anyway. Do you mind upvoting this question? :)

Comment: I changed the title, now I upvoted. You need to know that Bitcoin doesn't have such a thing as "progress". Mining is about trying a random puzzle, every hash your computer calculates has an equal chance of finding a block, regardless of how long you have been looking for that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically I went ahead and moved the database (mysql) and rebuilt the pushpool, stratum and litecoind sources on linux.

Comment: Pretty much what I said

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only person using the pool server, it doesn't matter how many shares you have -- all the profits are yours. Who would you be sharing them with?

Comment: It's me and my friends. Shares are kept in the database, which i will move over to the new server as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

1. To move work stats/shares you have to move those stored data. In your case probably a database.
2. You can use the same binaries if the new computer runs the same operating system on the same architecture. Otherwise just recompile them.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and recompiled them.